# How do vec attributes/accessors work in wgsl

Tags: wgsl

Hi this is a simple question.

I'm trying to read and understand a shader function which makes use of `vec3<f32>` variable types.

I don't understand what is that `.zzzz` key for:

```
  var myvar: vec3<f32> = vec3<f32>(1.3, 3.3, 3.3);
  myvar.zzzz; // ??
  myvar.xy; // ??
```

I can only understand `myvar.x`, `myvar.y`, `myvar.z`, but what happens when you combine or repeat those keys?

I can't yet find it in the [official](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/) documentation unfortunately.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a swizzle, also called convenience letterings in the spec. The spec section 7.7.1 says:

> The convenience letterings can be applied in any order, including duplicating letters as needed. The provided number of letters must be between 1 and 4

There are letterings for `x`, `y`, `z`, `w` and `r`, `g`, `b`, `a`. (Note, they can not be mixed.)

So `zzzz` means make a `vec4` initialized with the `z` component in each spot. The `xy` means make a `vec2` initialized with the `x` and `y` components.

Answer (score 0):

So, after looking at [this example](https://www.w3.org/TR/WGSL/#example-78b3a51f), my best guess is that `myvar.zzzz` returns a `vec4<f32>` initialised with the z component of the `myvar` vector.

So if `a_var = vec<f32>(1.0, 2.0, 3.0)`, then `b_var = a_var.zzzz` is equal to `(3.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0)`